# Run jar configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, jar, intellij-idea

Is there any option in IntelliJ IDEA to create a configuration to run an external jar like the external tools configurations in Eclipse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IDEA does not have a dedicated "Executable JAR" run/debug configuration. It does sound like a nice new feature. I'd recommend you request it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Despite that, there are two options to run an executable JAR.

**OPTION 1**

You can define a normal application run/debug configuration and define the executable JAR via the `VM options`. Here's an example:
[image]

**OPTION 2**

You can create an "External Tool" definition via *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > External Tools*. (Click the Help button in the dialog for details on the fields). You can run it via the *Tools* menu, or by assigning it a keyboard shortcut in the Keymap settings. The one downside here is that External Tools are defined at the IDE level and not a Project level. So that definition will show for all Projects. However, using the "Groups" option in the External Tools to group all configurations for a Project can add some structure.

Comment: Hi Mark,

thank you. The option 2 did the trick. Option 1 gave me some errors because IntelliJ parameters:

unrecognized  arguments: '-Didea.launcher.port=7532' ...

Comment: The current IDEA version (14.1.3) seems to have this feature implemented as "JAR Application" Run/Debug Configuration.