# Remote configuration debugging problem with IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, intellij-idea

After I asked in [Run jar configuration in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840999/run-jar-configuration-in-intellij-idea), I could create a new external configuration to run a jar within IntelliJ-Idea.

Unfortunately although I can run a jar configuration with Intellij now I've found a new weird issue. I'm trying to run that jar file and debug it remotely, so I create a new remote configuration with IntelliJ too attached to the address flag within the -Xrunjdwp JVM property:

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n -jar myjar.jar

This remote configuration connects to that port properly:

Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:1044', transport: 'socket' ...

But when I take some action related to the jar configuration, remote configuration doesn't seem to be aware of it. The most weird thing is if I run the jar configuration from command line or another IDE as Eclipse, remote configuration allows now to debug the code associated to the jar file in IntelliJ-Idea.

Comment: can you describe your problem in details?

Comment: the problem is that I run my app as a jar file within IntelliJ and to debug it I create a remote configuration that is listening at my app in a specific port. It seems that remote configuration is connected properly but when I execute something in my app I can't debug it. Weird thing is if I run my app outside of IntelliJ, I can debug using my remote configuration in IntelliJ

Comment: do you add all necessary debug flags when running from IDEA? (and the 'weird thing' is not weird. This is what remote configuration is for)

Comment: Hi Michal,thank you for your answer. Yes, in fact I use the same flags that I use from command line or with Eclipse. But it doesn't work with IntelliJ. 

Remote configuration connects properly but it can't debug through the code. I thought that it happened because source code wasn't attached to remote configuration but it wasn't the reason apparently.